# Convert Python dict files into MATLAB struct

Tags: python, matlab, dictionary, struct

I have a function in Python that outputs a dict. I run this function into MATLAB and save the output to a parameter (say `tmp`) which is a dict of nested other dicts itself. Now I want to convert this file into a useful format such as structure.

To elaborate: `tmp` is a dict. `data = struct(tmp)` is a structure but the fields are other dicts. I tried to go through every field and convert it individually, but this is not very efficient.

Another option: I have the output saved in a JSON file and can load it into MATLAB. However, it is still not useable.

Comment: scipy has some helpful features for io between python and matlab: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html

Answer (score 0):

So python -> MATLAB is a bit tricky with dictionaries/structs because the type of object that MATLAB is expecting is a dictionary object where each key is a single variable you want from python as a simple data type (array,int, etc).  It doesn't like having nested dictionaries.

I recommend 
1: Store each dictionary separately instead of as part of a higher level object.
or 2: even though it is not very nice converting the structs to individual variables.

MATLAB should be able to handle simple non-nested structures like that.